# Keep active state button ngClass / ngFor Bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using some buttons to filter data, I want to know how I can keep the active state of that button or assign a style depending on the filter that is activated at that moment, how can I achieve this?

My stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/query-collections-in-angularfire2

```
<button *ngFor="let categoria of categorias" (click)="filtrarData(categoria.nombre)" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mx-1">{{ categoria.nombre }}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ngClass`. when the selected value is equal to the value in HTML. Add `active` class.
And when you click reset. Just remove `currentValue`

```
HTML:
 [ngClass]="{'active': categoria.nombre === currentValue}"

Component.ts:

filtrarData(categoriaToFilter: string) {
  this.currentValue = categoriaToFilter;
}

getAvisos() {
  this.currentValue = '';
}
```

Don't forget to import Renderer2.

Comment: It works fine but there is a detail when I press the other reset button, that is, when I'm not in that state it's still activated. Is there any way to deactivate it when I have already left the event?

Comment: Hi @PacoZevallos. I changed the answer to remove active class when click reset button or other tab

Comment: `Error: Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined.`

Comment: Hi @PacoZevallos, Just remove `event` in function `filtrarData()`. And it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass for this

```
    <button 
      class="btn"
      *ngFor="let categoria of categorias" 
      (click)="filtrarData(categoria.nombre)"
      [ngClass]="categoria.selected ? 'activeButton' : 'normalButotn'>
   </button>
```

Comment: I have tried it but it does not generate any change in the state

Comment: So if you want to refresh the UI when you change the state then you need to make the update in a Immutable way so the component life cycle kicks in and components re renders again and refreshes the UI.